# Use derived output from a series of commands to egrep from pstree -p command

Tags: grep, command-substitution, pstree

I have the following long one liner which essentially provides a list of PIDs with a '|' delim character

```
echo $(lsof -p $(pgrep -f dosemu | tr '\012' ,) | grep '/media/datadrv' | awk '{print $2" - " $9}' | grep 'DBASE1.RES' | awk '{print $1}') | sed 's/\s\+/|/g'
```

this output something similar to `19066|19500`

What I want to do is use this to feed into the `pstree` command using `egrep`.

for example the following command gives me what i need

```
pstree -p | egrep '19066|19500'
```

What I cant figure out is how to feed the results of the first command into the second.

**Update**
Thanks to Goro's answer the complete one liner was :-

```
pstree -p | egrep $(echo $(lsof -p $(pgrep -f dosemu | tr '\012' ,) | grep '/media/datadrv' | awk '{print $2" - " $9}' | grep 'DBASE1.RES' | awk '{print $1}') | sed 's/\s\+/|/g')
```

Comment: Hellow @l0ckm4. If I understand correctly, you would like to feed `19066|19500` to the command `pstree -p` I mean, you would like to feed the numbers in the flag `-p` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the linear a variable name

```
var=$(echo $(lsof -p $(pgrep -f dosemu | tr '\012' ,) | grep '/media/datadrv' | awk '{print $2" - " $9}' | grep 'DBASE1.RES' | awk '{print $1}') | sed 's/\s\+/|/g')
```

Then feed `var` into `pstree` as follows:

```
pstree -p $var
```

If you would like to feed one of the numbers `19066|19500`, you can use `sed` to convert `|` to tab `\t`, then `awk` the number of interest as follows:

```
first_number=$(echo ${var} | sed 's/|/\t/g' | awk '{print $1}' )
19066
 pstree -p ${first_number}
```

Comment: Thanks Goro - I made it a one liner thanks to your answer